# Dynamic field is extra?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have defined an EventSubscriber with two possibilities, one of which adds a radio button with a variable number of buttons.  All appears to behave as expected unless one of the radio buttons is checked.  When checked, I get the

> This form should not contain extra fields.

error.

How can this be avoided?

Some code:

#### Subscriber

```
class AddV2FieldsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    private $factory;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory) {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
    }

    public function preSetData(DataEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        if (null === $data) {
            return;
        }
        // check if the client object is v1: id exists, dateAdded is null
        $n = $data->getMembers()->count();
        if (!$data->getId() || $data->getDateAdded()) {
            $date = new \DateTime();
            $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('dateAdded', 'date', $date, array(
                    'widget' => 'choice',
                    'format' => 'MM/dd/yyyy',
                    'pattern' => '{{ year }}-{{ month }}-{{ day }}',
                    'years' => range(Date('Y'), Date('Y') - 5),
                    'required' => false,
                    'input' => 'datetime',
                ))
                    );
            $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('active', 'hidden', 'Yes')
                    );
            $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('updated', 'hidden', 'No')
                    );
            $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('sex', 'choice', null, array(
                    'choices' => array('Male' => 'Male', 'Female' => 'Female'),
                    'empty_value' => "Select a gender",
                    'required' => false))
                    );
            $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('dob', 'dob_age', null)
                    );
        } 
        elseif ($n && !$data->getDateAdded())
        {
            $members = $data->getMembers();
            // build choices array with member ids
            $choices = array();
            foreach ($members as $member) {
                $choices[$member->getId()] = 'Yes';
            }
            $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('isClient', 'choice', null, array(
                        'choices' => $choices,
                        'empty_value' => false,
                        'required' => false,
                        'mapped' => false,
                        'expanded' => true,
                        'label' => 'isClient',
                    )));
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Another way to ask the question: how to give each field added by the subscriber the same name!

Comment: The way to get each field to have the same name is to put the subscriber in the ClientType and add as many choices as there are members, with member id as the value.  (I'll post this when I'm able.)  The challenge not yet met is to get each radio button in its own table row!  Experiments with widgets not yet successful.

Comment: Always add the most relevant tags that bring the largest number of *users*. This goes into the PHP users class, so you might have gotten more than 10 views if you had included it; a lot of people ignore questions that aren't tagged to what they look for. The forms tag, btw, is alright but won't really do much but maybe assist in searches like `[php] [symfony] [forms]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, in this case, was to use the debugger to find out what Symfony determined were extra fields.  Turned out there were some hard-wired hidden fields in the template that needed to be removed.  Doh!